# Rails 3 Polymorphic Association between one MongoMapper model and one/many Active Record model/s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongodb, mongomapper

I have a Record model (Active Record) that stores some custom logs.

Record is in polymorphic association with all the other model in my app, and I can effectively log what I want hooking my Record methods in the other controllers.

What I need:

To have the logs in a separate database.

So I have to:

1. Be able to manage two different databases in my apllication (one is Postgres/ActiveRecord and the other one is MongoDB/MongoMapper)
2. Generate a polymorphic association between my Record model, now with MongoMapper, and the rest of my Active Record models.

That way I can persist my logs to the MongoDB database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be done.

To create a polymorphic association you need both the class and an id. Idiomatically the fields will be named `<assoc>_type` and `<assoc>_id`<sup>‡</sup>.  You will need to do some wiring up to make everything work.

1. Create a MongoMapper::Document Class with the keys `<assoc>_type` and `<assoc>_id` with the correct types (I believe MongoMapper allows `Class` as a key type) along with any other keys you may need.
2. Define the method `<assoc>` and `<assoc>=`

   ```
   def assoc
     assoc_type.find(assoc_id)
   end

   def assoc=(input)
      assoc_type = input.class #STI makes this more complicated we must store the base class
      asspc_id = input.id
   end
   ```
3. Possibly add a method to your ActiveRecord models allowing them to access you MongoMapper logging class. If there are a lot, you may want to build a module and include it in all the classes that need that kind of functionality.

‡ replace  with something meaningful for you application like 'reference' or 'subject'

Comment: Thanks John, I managed this in the end thanks to your answer.