# Creating Association between mongodb and active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, activerecord

How can I create association like has_many, has_and_belongs_to_many, belongs_to between mongodb models and active record models for example. I have a class `Item` which is  using mongoid and I have another class `ItemType` that inherits from `ActiveRecord`

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :extra_fields, class_name: "ItemType"
end

class ItemType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Following link might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883643/rails-3-polymorphic-association-between-one-mongomapper-model-and-one-many-activ

Answer (score 1):

In mongoDB `references_many` and `referenced_in` are equal to has_many and belongs_to. Also there is another way to achieve has_many and belongs_to relation in mongoDB using `embeds_many` and `embedded_in`.

If you want to fetch record of child individually then you should go for `references_many` and `referenced_in`. And if child always come with parent only then you should go for `embeds_many` and `embedded_in`.

In case of `embeds_many` and `embedded_in` child nest with parent in mongo object and in case of `references_many` and `referenced_in` there are to different mongo object of child and parent with reference key.